# How to differentiate logs on the Error Reporting in the GCloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We have two clusters with multiple namespaces in each project. However our Error Reporting groups all errors together in the whole project and marking them as ‘gke_instances’ - there must be a better way to track where is the error coming from exactly (cluster/namespace/workload name)?

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?

Comment: The [13 Dec 2019 error reporting release notes](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/release-notes#December_13_2019) suggest it may now replace "gke_instances" with pod labels `k8s-pod/serving_knative_dev/service` and `k8s-pod/serving_knative_dev/revision`. I'm yet to try, but I stumbled on this question while looking.